# How establish MS ACCESS connectivity

Tags: jsp, ms-access

I want to learn and use MS ACCESS in my application (jsp application). Is it necessary to install any drivers externally to work with ACCESS?

and please provide me some info. and piece of code that helpful to use access in my application..

Thank you......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple google search wud have helped u. I guess

however,

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);
```

And in addition u need to register yr database file with odbc connection at

***Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools\Data Sources***

on Windows.

U can get drivers from [Java Driver Portal](http://industry.java.sun.com/products/jdbc/drivers)  Go for driver type -4

And u may laso chk inbuilt libraries provided by yr IDE. JDBC-ODBC lib shall do yr work

This should be quite simple. Hope it helps!!

Comment: thank you so much MalTec. and one more help needed. What to specify in place of url

Comment: that is yr database url.. jdbc:[subprotocol]:node/port]/[databaseName]  jdbc:odbc:localhost/dbname